# Confluence Macro vs Confluence Gadget

Tags: confluence

In Atlassian Confluence you can develop custom Macro or Gadget. What is the difference between these two? From what I have seen: "Gadgets are generated by scripts that run entirely in the user's web browser, not on the Confluence server"
What are the implications of it?

Comment: Gadgets are external, provided by gmail or igoogle for example, while macros are internally supplied by confluence or custom ones created by you. Macros will be limited to working with data accessible on the confluence page they're used on. Gadgets can do anything you can accomplish with javascript and html pretty much. Could you clarify what you are looking for in terms of 'implications?'

Answer (score 0):

IMU gadget may stop working when your company's firewall blocks access to its provider, as soon as it's hosted outside of the corporate WAN perimeter; macroses won't stop as they're hosted on the Condluence server which is inside your company's perimeter.

Not applicable for On-Demand instances, though.